# Flask Route Pattern Matching Order

Tags: python, pattern-matching, flask

Given that [Flask Routes are not pattern matched from top to bottom](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/design/#the-routing-system), how does one deal with the following problem?

I have the following routes:

1. `/<poll_key>/close`
2. `/<poll_key>/<participant_key>`

If I make a request to `http://localhost:5000/example-poll-key/close`, Flask matches it as pattern 2, assigning the string 'close' to the `<participant_key>` URL parameter. How can I make the `<poll_key>/close` route get matched before the `<participant_key>` route?

Comment: Try create the static route pattern before the dynamic one. It seems the order matters.

Answer (score 6):

See my other answer to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17146563/880326.

Looks like the best solution is to add your own converters and create routes as

```
/<poll_key>/close
/<poll_key>/<no(close):participant_key>
```

where the `no` converter is defined

```
class NoConverter(BaseConverter):

    def __init__(self, map, *items):
        BaseConverter.__init__(self, map)
        self.items = items

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in self.items:
            raise ValidationError()
        return value
```

---

**Update:**

I missed `match_compare_key`:

1. for `static` endpoint: `(True, -2, [(0, -6), (1, 200)])`
2. for `/<poll_key>/close`: `(True, -2, [(1, 100), (0, -5)])`
3. for `/<poll_key>/<participant_key>`: `(True, -2, [(1, 100), (1, 100)])`

This means that `static` has higher priority than the others and `close` has higher priority than `<participant_key>`.

Example:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.add_url_rule('/<poll_key>/close', 'close',
                 lambda **kwargs: 'close\t' + str(kwargs))
app.add_url_rule('/<poll_key>/<participant_key>', 'p_key',
                 lambda **kwargs: 'p_key\t' + str(kwargs))


client = app.test_client()

print client.get('/example-poll-key/close').data
print client.get('/example-poll-key/example-participant-key').data
```

This outputs:

```
close   {'poll_key': u'example-poll-key'}
p_key   {'participant_key': u'example-participant-key', 'poll_key': u'example-poll-key'}
```

Looks like this is the right behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip. I didn't know about Converters. This was a great solution for simplified example I asked about, however I have a lot more keywords than 'close' that I did not want to match the `participant_key` url component. So effectively saying "match if not in the set (close, admin, add, etc)" would get pretty long. I ended up using this [RegexConverter solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870188/does-flask-support-regular-expressions-in-its-url-routing) and making sure my `participant_key` url component had a certain prefix.

Comment: I was a little wrong, see my update. Can you get rules `arguments` and `_weights` values for this two rules?