# Flask - Dynamic URLs

Tags: python, url, flask

When I do too many dynamic URLs my stylesheets stop working.  For instance.  My stylesheet is in my layout.html file under /static/css/style.css

Code:

```
#works
@app.route('/<var1>', methods=['blah'])
def someFunc(var1):
    # code

#works
@app.route('/<var1>/<var2>', methods=['blah'])
def someNewFunc(var1, var2):
    # code

#no errors displayed but my stylesheet stops loading
@app.route('/<var1>/<var2>/<var3>', methods=['blah'])
def finalFunc(var1, var2, var3):
    # code
```

So I've got two questions.  First, does Flask not support dynamic URLs past two?  Second, is there a better way to go about this (i.e. is there a convention I should follow)?

Comment: Why is your stylesheet going through a view? `url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')` will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your routes are ambiguous. When the browser requests your stylesheet at `/static/css/style.css` Flask finds two matching routes:

- `/static/<path:path>` with `path=css/style.css`
- `/<var1>/<var2>/<var3>` with `var1=static`, `var2=css` and `var3=style.css`

The routing algorithm used by Flask and Werkzeug prefers the longest route when multiple ones match and that makes the second one win.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868916/flask-route-pattern-matching-order) shows a possible way to solve this problem using custom route converters.

But my recommendation is that you change your dynamic URL so that it is not so generic. You can add a fixed component to it, for example `/some-prefix/<var1>/<var2>/<var3>`.