# Catch all path in flask app

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, flask

I writing an app in Angular + Flask hosted on heroku. I've been looking to use html5mode to use `myapp.co/register` for oauth. The problem with html5mode is that server needs to rewrite url if someone refreshes the page or clicks the link that is not root. I tried to use [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/) snippet to catch them all, but it doesn't work.

```
@app.route("/", defaults={"path": ""})
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def index(path):
  print path
  return make_response(open(app.static_folder + "index.html").read())
```

output 404

```
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jan/2014 13:41:48] "GET /ass HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

App got root that servers index.html and /api/v1/ that is RESTful api

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code will catch all urls if you do not have any more routes with more highest priority. But look like it should return `500` error (because I hope you do not have `<app_path>/staticindex.html` and use unsafe method to send file).

So if you have another rules you must look at rule priority (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17146563/880326).

If you have error with this route better use:

```
@app.route("/", defaults={"path": ""})
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def index(path)
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, "index.html")
```

Comment: Thanks. By unsafe you mean that url is mapped to file path? whats the benefit of send_from_directory?

Comment: Yes, somebody can try use send `../` or `~/` to path (probably it will not work with URL, but probably you can get it with any another way). `send_from_directory` (see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory) is enough clever to avoid relative paths for directory with `safe_join` and have many options with `send_file`. For example flask `static` route used `send_from_directory`. It good for development, but for production better process this files with nginx or replace it with CDN URLs if you wish.

Comment: For anyone using Flask with AngularJS, if you wish for your app to display current route on angular rather than spit out a 404 whenever you refresh the page, use @app.route("/<path:path>") and set path parameter to None.

Comment: i had to remove the "static_url_path" from the flask initialization in order to make this work

Answer (score 24):

You need to use something more than you have:

```
@app.route("/", defaults={"path": ""})
@app.route("/<string:path>") <--- this is missing
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def index(path):
  print path
  return make_response(open(app.static_folder + "index.html").read())
```

So:

```
@app.route("/<string:path>")
```

is missing. It catches string variables (not path), so in your case just `ass` from your example, when you try to hit http://localhost:5000/ass.

Comment: I am wondering why is this missing in the official documentation. See: [Flask | Single-Page Applications](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/singlepageapplications/)