# How do I sort Flask/Werkzeug routes in the order in which they will be matched?

Tags: flask, url-routing, werkzeug

I have a function that I'm using to list routes for my Flask site and would like to be sure it is sorting them in the order in which they will be matched by Flask/Werkzeug.

Currently I have

```
def routes(verbose, wide, nostatic):
    """List routes supported by the application"""

    for rule in sorted(app.url_map.iter_rules()):
        if nostatic and rule.endpoint == 'static':
            continue

        if verbose:
            fmt = "{:45s} {:30s} {:30s}" if wide else "{:35s} {:25s} {:25s}"
            line = fmt.format(rule, rule.endpoint, ','.join(rule.methods))
        else:
            fmt = "{:45s}" if wide else "{:35s}"
            line = fmt.format(rule)

        print(line)
```

but this just seems to sort the routes in the order I've defined them in my code.

How do I sort Flask/Werkzeug routes in the order in which they will be matched?

---

Another approach: Specifying a host and a path and seeing what rule applies.

```
    urls = app.url_map.bind(host)
    try:
        m = urls.match(match, "GET")
        z = '{}({})'.format(m[0], ','.join(["{}='{}'".format(arg, m[1][arg]) for arg in m[1]] +
                                           ["host='{}'".format(host)]))
        return z
    except NotFound:
        return
```

Comment: They are showing in that order because that is how they are stored. See https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/routing.py#L1397 and within that https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/routing.py#L1489 for the inner workings :)

Comment: @JoeDoherty: So is `sorted(app.url_map.iter_rules())` putting them in the order in which they will be matched?

Comment: ``for rule in self.map._rules:`` I don't think they are sorted. Can I ask what you need the exact order for?

Comment: @JoeDoherty: For the function above. Make sure they're being checked in the order I intend. So: how do I get them in the order they will be matched?

Comment: Get rid of the `sorted()` and that should be correct. There is no reason to sort it.

Comment: @JoeDoherty: Ah, I see. Didn't understand the comment at first. That looks right.

Comment: @JoeDoherty: Though, *are* these in the right order: `/`  `/<path:location>/<file>`   `/<file>`   `/<path:location>/`  `/static/<path:filename>` ? That seems wrong (for one thing, the static one ought to be first, right?)

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Both will be highlighted but the simplest will be chosen so "static" will be matched before <path:location>. I use /about and /<username> and about will never be matched in the second. Its more complex than the order they appear in. That is why I asked earlier what you need this for.

Comment: @JoeDoherty: So there's no way to list them in an order that corresponds to how they will be matched?

Comment: Not really because they will all be checked and then a sort of weight given to them based of complexity. What issue is this causing?

Comment: @JoeDoherty: Mostly I want a way of checking what rule is going to apply to a given path and host, but I'm getting results that make no sense. For example, any path beginning with `static` seems to invoke a special static rule, even if `static_folder` is not `static` (though the first chunk of code above responds as expected, listing the changed `static_folder` as the match; while the second chunk does not, never getting to static at all; even though the actual application, always seems to respond to paths beginning with 'static' with the static endpoint, regardless of `static_folder`).

Comment: @JoeDoherty: The problem began [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28663065/656912), though that's not really the issue now, since I can get around that by just changing the name of the folder where things are kept to something other than 'static' (which I had stupidly used before).

Comment: @JoeDoherty: So, to be a bit clearer (I hope): if I navigate to `something.com/static/xyz` the special static rule is invoked, but if I use the second bit of code above to see what rule is invoked for `host=something.com` and `match=/static/xyz`, the static rule is NOT matched. And if I change the `static_folder` to something else, I get the same result. Meanwhile, the first chunk of code lists paths with  `static_folder` mapping to the static rule.

Comment: @JoeDoherty: I think you've answered this question though: That's the "order", such as it is; but it doesn't to what I think it does. I'd accept that as an answer here, and I'll take the other issues to a new question about how to figure out what rule will match a given path and host (and why my code doesn't behave the way my application does; and how to get around the sticky/cryptic 'static' rule).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each request Flask/Werkzeug reordered `self.map.update()` rules if it need with route weights (see my another answer [URL routing conflicts for static files in Flask dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135006/url-routing-conflicts-for-static-files-in-flask-dev-server/17146563#17146563)).

You can found that `Map.update` method update `_rules` (see https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/routing.py#L1313).

So you can do the same thing:

```
sorted(current_app.url_map._rules, key=lambda x: x.match_compare_key())
```

Or if all routes already loaded and any request done (called `Map.build` or `Map.match`) just use `app.url_map._rules` - it will be sorted. In request `app.url_map._rules` already sorted, because `Map.match` was called before dispatcher (match rule with dispatcher).

You also can found that `Map.update` called in `Map.iter_rules`, so you can just use this method `current_app.url_map.iter_rules()` (see https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/routing.py#L1161).

Comment: So `sorted(... x.match_compare_key())` and `current_app.url_map.iter_rules()` will give the same result (they do for me) and that result will be "sorted", correct?

Comment: What's confusing me is if that's true, paths that begin with `static` are behaving very strangely. Both on my development machine and my server the first bit of (listing) code lists the static rule last, and that's also how the second bit of code works (matching `static` with a non-static rule). That's all consistent. And so is he actual application behavior on my development machine: my rules and not the static rule match a static path. BUT on the server, (despite both bits of code in my question putting static last), the static rule catches any static paths!

Comment: All examples in my answer should give same result. I not understood completely your second comment, but you should understand that `static` route the same as another - it have rule and dispatcher (endpoint) that return files from some directory. On you prod server static path can intercepted by nginx, apache or another web server according to config.

Comment: So what's probably happening is that the server is [intercepting paths that begin with 'static' before Flask/Werkzeug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28697176/656912) even has a chance to process them?

Comment: Maybe, I do not know, but it look very strange that AWS smarter than developer and intercept this rule (not statics, not assets or something else). You can change `static_url_path` of your application to unpredictable and check is it still correct (it will work correctly when you use `url_for` to generate static urls).

Comment: As near as I can tell `static_url_path` doesn't seem to affect what AWS-EB does.